# Update data if exists

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I can update the data if the product size is exists. Assume that the table has a existing product_size (size 7) where product_stocks is 15, and I want to add size. For example I added a product stocks(15pcs.) on product_size(size 7), so the product stocks of size 7 is will be 30pcs. My problem is how can I add the data if the product size is not exists?

```vb
   Public Sub addProductsExtension()
        Try
            dbConnection()
            search_query = "SELECT * FROM tblproducts_extension WHERE product_code = @product_code;"
            command = New SqlCommand
            With command
                .Connection = connection
                .CommandText = search_query
                .Parameters.Clear()
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_code", productsView.txtPCode.Text)
                dataReader = .ExecuteReader()
                If dataReader.HasRows Then
                    While dataReader.Read
                        updateExtension()
                        MsgBox("Updated stocks.")
                    End While
                Else
                    addExtension()
                End If
            End With
        Catch ex As SqlException
            MsgBox("Error : " + ex.Message)
        Finally
            connection.Close()
            command.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub 

    'these are the codes for adding size and stocks
    Public Sub addExtension()
        Try
            dbConnection()
            insert_query = "INSERT INTO tblproducts_extension(product_size, product_stocks, product_code) VALUES(@product_size, @product_stocks, @product_code);"
            command = New SqlCommand
            With command
                .Connection = connection
                .CommandText = insert_query
                .Parameters.Clear()
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_size", productsView.comboSize.SelectedItem)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_stocks", productsView.txtProductStocks.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_code", productsView.txtPCode.Text)
                result = .ExecuteNonQuery()
                If result = 0 Then
                    MsgBox("Error in adding data.")
                Else
                    MsgBox("Successfully added data.")
                End If
            End With
        Catch ex As SqlException
            MsgBox("Error : " + ex.Message)
        Finally
            connection.Close()
            command.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub

    'these are the codes for updating stocks if the product size is exists
Public Sub updateExtension()
        Try
            dbConnection()
            update_query = "UPDATE tblproducts_extension SET product_stocks = product_stocks + @product_stocks WHERE product_size = @product_size AND product_code = @product_code;"
            command = New SqlCommand
            With command
                .Connection = connection
                .CommandText = update_query
                .Parameters.Clear()
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_size", productsView.comboSize.SelectedItem)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_stocks", productsView.txtProductStocks.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_code", productsView.txtPCode.Text)
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
        Catch ex As SqlException
            MsgBox("Error : " + ex.Message)
        Finally
            connection.Close()
            command.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Are you asking for a problem in this code or are you asking if there is a better way to do it?

Comment: Both brother :)

Comment: Your select find a product only by the product id while you need also the size value. This should make your code run albeit it could be simplified using the MERGE keyword

Comment: I'm not familiar on that keyword. Btw, how to use it? Thanks anyways.

Comment: Is your problem that you get error when product_stocks = 0? And that is because you didn't set default to 0 in your `productsView.txtProductStocks.Text`. So your trying to add product_stocks=NULL or "" + @product_stocks..

Comment: Oh man, it worked! I added the product size on select statement. Thanks. Btw how do I show the "No product code found." if the entered product code  in textbox is not already in the database?

Comment: After the Else, befor AddExtentions()

Comment: I, and many others, strongly recommend that you don't use AddWithValue: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: What should I use?

Comment: So If I use .Parameters.Add(), the syntax will be; .Parameters.Add("@product_stocks", SqlDbType.Int, 30).Value = productsView.txtProductStocks.Text ?? Please correct if it is wrong. I would change it into .Parameters.Add()

Comment: @AndrewMorton check my syntax on .Parameters.Add()

Comment: @Janjan Personally I prefer the form `.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = @product_stocks, .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, .Value = Integer.Parse(productsView.txtProductStocks.Text)}`. N.B. You should use [Option Strict On](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/311329/option-explicit-and-option-strict-in-visual-basic--net-and-in-visual-b) to get Visual Studio to point out some types of problem for you.

Comment: Okay, but my syntax is correct am I right?

Comment: @JhonTh Your syntax is incorrect: you are assigning a string to an integer variable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48576837/the-type-initializer-module-error?noredirect=1#comment84151744_48576837 Can you help me to fix this? @AndrewMorton

Comment: @JhonTh My advice is still: don't use AddWithValue and do use Option Strict On.

Comment: Yes, I changed my code to .Parameters.Add()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current code doesn't work because, in the initial SELECT, you search only for product_code. This is not enough to decide if you want to add or update a record because you need to add the new quantity to a product with a specific size. So you can simply add this other parameter to your select query (like you do in the UPDATE) and your code should work as is.

However, we can use the [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) keyword that will update or insert your data with just one call.

```
string query = @"MERGE tblproducts_extension T
                 USING (1 as dummy) as S 
                 ON T.product_size = @product_size AND T.product_code = @product_code
                 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
                     INSERT (product_code, product_size, product_stocks)
                     VALUES (@product_code, @product_size, @newQuantity)
                 WHEN MATCHED THEN 
                     UPDATE SET product_stocks = T.product_stocks + @newQuantity;";
```