# The type initializer <module> error

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I'm making a search and retrieve it on datagridview, but I got this error "The type initializer for  threw an exception.", after I clicked the button employeesView in the dashboard (menu). How to fix it? Thanks guys!!

***Error:***

```
    Private Sub btnEmployees_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEmployees.Click
        employeesView.TopLevel = False
        Me.panelMain.Controls.Add(employeesView)
        Me.panelHeader.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 160, 220)
        employeesView.BringToFront()
        employeesView.Show()
    End Sub
```

**publicVariables.vb**

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Module publicVariables

    Public connection As SqlConnection
    Public command As SqlCommand
    Public dataReader As SqlDataReader
    Public dataAdapter As SqlDataAdapter

    Public dataTable As DataTable

    Public search_query As String
    Public insert_query As String
    Public delete_query As String
    Public update_query As String

    Public result As Integer

    Public getNumber As String = "0"

    Public productsView As New Products
    Public dashboardView As New Dashboard
    Public employeesView As New Employee
    Public salesView As New Sales
    Public logsView As New LogManager

End Module
```

**Codes for Search:**

```
Public Sub retrieveEmployeesforSearch()
        Try
            dbConnection()
            search_query = "SELECT * FROM tblemployee_information as emp_info INNER JOIN tblemployee_account as emp_account ON emp_account.employee_number = emp_info.employee_number WHERE emp_info.employee_first_name LIKE @employee_first_name ORDER BY emp_info.employee_first_name;"
            command = New SqlCommand
            With command
                .Connection = connection
                .CommandText = search_query
                .Parameters.Clear()
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@employee_first_name", employeesView.txtSearchEmployee.Text)
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
            dataTable = New DataTable
            dataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter
            dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable)
            employeesView.EmployeeDGV.DataSource = dataTable
        Catch ex As SqlException
            MsgBox("Error : " + ex.Message)
        Finally
            connection.Close()
            command.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Retrieve search data if textbox.text textchanged

```
Private Sub txtSearchEmployee_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtSearchEmployee.TextChanged
        retrieveEmployeesforSearch()
    End Sub
```

Comment: What is the data type of employeesView and did you initialize it?

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b The OP's code show this variable in the module   Public employeesView As New Employee

Comment: How to fix it guys?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean but I think there is also some wrong with this code:

```
search_query = "SELECT * FROM tblemployee_information as emp_info INNER JOIN tblemployee_account as emp_account ON emp_account.employee_number = emp_info.employee_number WHERE emp_info.employee_first_name LIKE @employee_first_name ORDER BY emp_info.employee_first_name;"
```

you may refer from [this link](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/443188/Access-Select-query-in-vb-net). hopefully, it will help you.

Comment: @Peter Saul, your link refers to an Access database. The OP's question is tagged with SQL Server. Access SQL and Transact SQL have differences.

Comment: sorry about that. @jhon can you show us the lines for dbConnection()? tnx

Comment: Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Module connectionModule
    Public Sub dbConnection()
        Try
            connection = New SqlConnection
            connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=YEEZY\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBShop;Integrated Security=True"
            connection.Open()
        Catch ex As SqlException
            MsgBox("Error:  " + ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Module

Comment: I tried replicating your issue but to no avail. Can you like trap it where the error occurred?